# Button not being disabled in promise.then().finally()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, promise

I'm having an issue with an angularJS $http call that returns a promise which has a .then() and .finally() called against it (see below code):

```
    $scope.edit = function () {
        $('.alert').addClass('hidden');

        $scope.showError = false;
        $scope.showSuccess = false;

        var btn = $('#submit-link-edit');
        btn.button('loading');

        context.linksRepo.edit($scope.link)
            .then(
                function (response) { // success
                    $scope.showSuccess = true;

                    // if it works make sure we update all of our variables
                    cachedURL = $scope.link.URL;
                    $scope.cachedAKA = $scope.link.AKA;
                    $scope.cachedUpdateDate = $scope.link.UpdateDate;
                    $scope.cachedUpdatedBy = $scope.link.UpdatedBy;

                    // show completeness on button
                    btn.button('complete');
                },
                function (response) { // failure
                    $scope.showError = true;

                    // if it doesn't work reset our variables
                    $scope.link.URL = cachedURL;
                    $scope.link.AKA = $scope.cachedAKA;
                    $scope.errorMessage = response.data.Message;

                    // show save changes on button again
                    btn.button('reset');
                })
            .finally(
                function () {
                    // this doesn't work
                    $scope.editDisabled = true;
                });
    }
```

Basically I have a disabled button on my page that gets enabled through user input:

```
            <button id="submit-link-edit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="editDisabled" data-loading-text="Saving..." data-complete-text="Saved">
                Save Changes
            </button>
```

When the button is enabled and clicked, it calls my `$scope.edit` function which calls a method in my factory (`context`) that returns a promise. I use `.then()` to determine the success or failure of that call and set the button accordingly (have it say "Saved" or revert to "Save Changes" again) and then a `.finally()` to set the button back to disabled since I don't want them to be able to click it again without making input changes which will enable it for them.

**edit**
I switched my code over to use directives instead of direct DOM manipulation

It's probably worth noting (don't know why I forgot to mention it before) that `.button()` is from bootstrap.js for toggling enabled/disabled and the text on the button and I have a very strong feeling that something is breaking between the bootstrap script and the angular scripts both modifying the button.

Comment: Are you using button widget? if so you need to disable it by calling `.button('disable')`. By the way why are you doing DOM manipulation, you should probably be doing it the angular way...

Comment: Try btn.prop("disabled", "disabled");

Comment: What button is this? `btn.button('loading');` If this is a regular button then `prop('disabled', true)` is correct.

Comment: I've updated my question and switched my code over to directives, however it's having the same effect. Everything works fine but the end result is the button still being enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As another person stated, try it the angular way.  Then you can just reference variables on $scope in your .then and .finally methods.

```
<button ng-model="btn" ng-disabled="isBtnDisabled">Button</button>
```

Then you can set $scope.isBtnDisabled = true or false;

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

```
    <div ng-app="">
      <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <button ng-disabled="isBtnDisabled">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
<script>
  function Ctrl1($scope) {
    $scope.isBtnDisabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is the better practice of manipulating the DOM with angular, however this isn't working either.